# Can I do an API call before displaying local push notifications?

Tags: swift, unusernotificationcenter, usernotifications

Is it possible to do an API call before I actually display a scheduled local push notification? Because I have to do a "status check" on the server if I should still display the local push notification or not.

Unfortunately, we can't send the push from server because of certain decisions made.

There's this [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43370567/is-it-possible-to-trigger-an-api-call-before-displaying-local-notifications), but the answer is quite incomplete and the link included is no longer working.

Comment: I think, you can only be able to make an API Call while app is in FOREGROUND otherwise you can't. However you can do one thing, you can re-schedule all the notifications periodically

Comment: Then, is it possible to do a scheduled background call and then trigger the push depending on the "status" response?